# Help with JSON.deserialize

Tags: apex, json, deserialize

```
@AuraEnabled
    public static String clone(Group__c destinationGroup) {
        Savepoint sp = Database.setSavepoint();

        try {

            Group__c dest = (Group__c)JSON.deserialize(destinationGroup, Group__c.class);

            if ( String.isBlank(dest.Id) ) insert dest;

            cloneGroup.cloneGroups(dest.Id);

            return dest.Id;

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Database.rollback(sp);
            throw new AuraHandledException(ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void deserialize(Group__c, System.Type) from the type System.JSON

How to fix this error? I don't know how to deserialize.

Answer (score 0):

`destinationGroup` is already a `Group__c`. You don't need to deserialize it. If you pass in the object directly in LWC, you don't need to stringify and deserialize.

```
// LWC
clone({ destinationGroup: { sobjectType: 'Group__c', /* Other fields here */ }})
.then((result) => console.log('Group cloned'))
.catch((error) => console.log('Error creating group',error));
```

If you want to deserialize it, you can, but you need a String:

```
@AuraEnabled(cacheable=false) public static String clone(String destinationGroup) {
```

I don't recommend doing this if you can help it; the platform will already serialize objects for you if you pass in an Object.